# Sideways table with rotated header on multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating, landscape

I am trying to have a sideways table on multiple pages with the header rotated at 90 deg.

I have used `landscape` and `longtable` for the rotation and `multipage` span (`sidewaystable` doesn't work with `multipage` for some reason).
And I have used `\rotatebox{90}` for the header.

The header row of the table is too long. I would like to reduce it's height and have the text in those cells be on several "lines".

Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}          

\centering    
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Experiment No. }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Sample  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Temperature  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Sample Weight  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Tar Fraction  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Char Fraction  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Steam Flow Rate [ml/min]  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Nitrogen Flow Rate [ml/min]  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Reaction Distance  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Flow Rate/Sample Weight  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Residence Time [s]  }}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Stochiometric error  }}}  \hline \endhead %\\

017 & ABS & 700\Deg & 0.56 & 24.0\% & 0\% & 0.000 & 250.000 & 0.6 & 0.000 & 41.15 & 0.0 \\
029 & ABS & 700\Deg & 1.07 & 23.0\% & 0.0\% & 0.000 & 350.000 & 0.5 & 0.000 & 29.41 & 0.0 \\
021 & ABS & 700\Deg & 1.60 & 24.3\% & 0.0\% & 0.167 & 250.000 & 0.6 & 0.104 & 22.49 & 1.2 \
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please always post _complete_ small documents that show the problem. `\centering` has no effect on longtable. It isn't clear which text in your fragment you mean by "long text" nor where you want it to span. Each of the rotated headings apparently just needs a single column?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid I don't know how to interpret your statement, "I would like the long text in header to span on several row...". Do you intend to have different header rows for different pages, or the same header row for each page? If it's the latter, then your use of the `longtable` environment should get the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it like this? I used `\parbox`. The width of parbox may be adjusted as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
%\begin{sidewaystable}

\centering
%\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Experiment No. }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Sample  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Temperature  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Sample Weight  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Tar Fraction  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Char Fraction  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Steam Flow Rate [ml/min]  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Nitrogen Flow Rate [ml/min]  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Reaction Distance  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Flow Rate/Sample Weight  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Residence Time [s]  }}}}  &
{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{3cm}{\raggedright\textbf{Stochiometric error  }}}} \\
 \hline \endhead %\\

017 & ABS & \SI{700}{\degree} & 0.56 & 24.0\% & 0\% & 0.000 & 250.000 & 0.6 & 0.000 & 41.15 & 0.0 \\
029 & ABS & \SI{700}{\degree} & 1.07 & 23.0\% & 0.0\% & 0.000 & 350.000 & 0.5 & 0.000 & 29.41 & 0.0 \\
021 & ABS & \SI{700}{\degree} & 1.60 & 24.3\% & 0.0\% & 0.167 & 250.000 & 0.6 & 0.104 & 22.49 & 1.2 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also use `\SI{700}{\celsius}`. See the `siunitx` manual for using the SI units..

Comment: +1 for attempting (I couldn't guess what was required). Probably a `\raggedright` in the parboxes would help not stretch the titles so much.

Comment: @Harish Kumar - thanks that is exactly what I was looking for.